# Insert scrollbar in rCharts (highchart)

Tags: r, time-series, rcharts

Is it possible to insert a scrollbar in the x axis of a time series plot of rCharts (highchart)? I tried many options but I couldnt find out a way to do it.

Comment: Do you have a solution for this question ?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the [Range Selector:](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#rangeSelector)

It looks like this:
[image: Range selector]